# JavaScript game - Object that can not be crossed

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a project to do as I learn JavaScript.
This is a simple game. You have to go from the bottom to the top of the Canvas.
I would like to place a rock on the canvas what can not be crossed and the player needs to go around it.
Could you help me how to solve this problem?

This is how I control the player

```
Player.prototype.handleInput = function () {
    var self = this;
    console.log(self);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
        var keyName = event.which || event.keyCode;

        switch (keyName) {
            case true:
                return self.x = 0, self.y = 0;


            case 37:
            case 65:
            case 100:
                return self.x -= 20;

            case 38:
            case 87:
            case 104:
                return self.y -= 20;

            case 39:
            case 68:
            case 102:
                return self.x += 20;

            case 40:
            case 83:
            case 101:
                return self.y += 20;
        }
    })

}
```

This is the rock constructor

```
Rock = function(){
    this.x = getRandomInt(50, 700);
    this.y = getRandomInt(50, 400);
    this.width = 101;
    this.height = 171;
}
```

I have a collision detection as well what is from the MDN site

```
function objectCollision(obj1, obj2) {
    var rect1 = obj1;
    var rect2 = obj2;
    if (rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width &&
        rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
        rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height &&
        rect1.height + rect1.y > rect2.y) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have tried to solve different ways but I can not figure it out.
I need a solution when the player hit the rock from any sides than it can not move further that way.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your keyup event handler, try something like the following around the existing switch:

```
    var old_x = self.x;
    var old_y = self.y;
    switch (keyName) {
        ...
    }
    for (var i in obstacles) {
        if (obstacles[i] != self && objectCollision(self, obstacles[i])) {
            self.x = old_x;
            self.y = old_y;
            break;
        }
    }
```

I'm assuming you'll have an array of obstacles rather than just a single rock.